# Dapper Method using generics

Tags: c#, generics, dapper

I am trying to create a common dapper 'read' method.I am wanting to pass the return type in as a parameter to the method.I am unfamiliar with generics but have an idea that it could be done using generics. I'm thinking it will look something like this?

```
public static T ListReader<T>(string SQL, ref T returnType, string DbName = "TEST")
{
    using (IDbConnection cmd = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbName].ConnectionString))
    {
        return cmd.Query<returnType>(SQL).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing generics, which must be known at compile-time, with objects.

Remove that `returnType` that doesn't add anything useful and fix the return type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ListReader<T>(string SQL, string DbName = "TEST")
{
    using (IDbConnection cmd = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DbName].ConnectionString))
    {
        return cmd.Query<T>(SQL).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got it working! Think I need to go revise generics..